# Doubt on Complex Replacement technique (ODE)

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

[image: MIT notes on ODE]

---

1. How did he combine Equation 1 and 3, and ended up with equation 4 ?
2. And why did he introduced the 3rd Equation with $sin$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Equation (4) is the result of adding together Equation (2) and $i$ times Equation (3), the definition $z = x + iy$, and using the fact that these are linear ODEs.
2. The point of introducing Equation (3) is that this allows you to get to Equation (4) using Euler's formula. You can find a particular solution of Equation (4) by assuming the solution is a complex exponential. Then taking the real part of the resulting solution will give a solution to (2) (again, using the fact that the ODEs here are linear).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to note that 
$\dot{x} + k x = {B \over 2} (e^{i \omega t} + e^{-i \omega t})$.

Suppose $z_\omega$ is a solution to $\dot{z} + k z = e^{i \omega t}$, then
by superposition we see that
$x={B \over 2}(z_\omega + z_{-\omega})$ is
a
solution to the first equation.